# Not able to call exported virtual function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, mfc, virtual-functions

I have a MyApi.dll with exported class Base with a pure virtual function.Also I have 
a derived class having implementation of the virtual function in the same dll.
Factory function returns a derived class object.

```
#define MYAPI_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
class MYAPI_EXPORT base{ virtual int func() = 0;}
class MYAPI_EXPORT  derived: public base
{
   int func(){
      return 4;
   }
}
MYAPI_EXPORT void *factoryfunction()
{
void *obj = new derived;
return obj;
}
```

And below is the code which calls this derived function.

```
CString dllName = _T("MyApi.dll");
typedef void* (*fn)();


HINSTANCE hModule = ::AfxLoadLibrary(dllName);
if(hModule)
{
    fn pfn = (fn)GetProcAddress(hModule,"factoryFunction");
    Base* pcDerived = (Base*)pfn;

    pcDerived->func();
}
```

I loaded MyApi.dll using LoadLibrary.
Then I am calling a factory function returning derived class pointer which then calls the implemented function.The factory function returns the pointer to derived class object but the call to virtual function fails at runtime.
This did not help ->
   [Not necessary to export class with only virtual/inline functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549983/not-necessary-to-export-class-with-only-virtual-inline-functions)

Comment: Why not export both classes?

Comment: How does it fail? does it crash, return the wrong value, etc...

Comment: @brianbeuning I have tried that too. It does not work.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious It does not execute the function's code. The program quits at the call point.

Comment: i'm just going to assume that "quit" means it crashes. How about posting the code that calls the factory function and calls the member function since that's where it's "quiting". You might want to try putting a breakpoint at the location it "quits" and step into it to get a bit more information on what's going on.

Comment: I added an extrern "C" and exported the Derived class too then It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your method in a derived class as virtual and override. So it should look like following:

```
class MYAPI_EXPORT  derived: public base
{
    virtual int func() override {
        return 4;
    }
}
```

Just saying it's ovveride (or nothing at all, as in your case) will break everything

Comment: What? `virtual` is implicit when the base class defines a method with the same signature. And `override` doesn't actually *do* anything, it's just a Microsoft compiler extension that ensures you are actually overrriding a function in the base class. It doesn't change the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
fn pfn = (fn)GetProcAddress(hModule,"factoryFunction");
```

pfn is address of function.

you have to call that to get instanced object.

```
Base* pcDerived = (Base*)pfn();
```